# Best practices for Publishing an ASP.NET 5 app to Docker on Linux with Visual Studio

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2015, dockerfile

I follow the [example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNET5AppToDockerOnLinuxWithVisualStudio.aspx) to publish an ASP.NET app to Docker on Linux with Visual Studio.

However each time I modify the code and publish it again. It seems to create a new container and image. So it is sort of wasting space.

So what is the best practices here? How can I use the same container and just overwrite the previous image?

**EDIT**

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app/approot
ENTRYPOINT ["./web"]
```

Comment: I need to see the Dockerfile. Could you post your Dockerfile please?

Comment: @Robert, I updated the Dockerfile. It was generate by Visual Studio.

Comment: Not sure how you do this in VS, but in general, you can change `ADD . /app` to `VOLUME /app`, and then run your image with `docker run -v host_app_path:/app image_name` to mount your app to the image everytime, so that you can reuse the image when your app changes (assuming no new dependencies needed on the image)

Comment: @warmoverflow, if it is my first time to run/publish it. Which one should I select between `ADD` and `VOLUME`?

Comment: You should always use `VOLUME` if you plan to reuse the image

Comment: @warmoverflow, thanks. Another question is that I don't understand the the meaning of `WORKDIR`. Is there a true folder named as `/app/approot`? Also `ENTRYPOINT`, is there a true file `web`? I also can't find it.

Comment: `WORK_DIR` is the working directory of every command below this line. So there should be a directory called `/app/approot` inside the container. There must be a file `/app/approot/web`. Since you are using `ADD`, you must have an `approot/web` file in your current folder (on your computer, not Docker)

Comment: @warmoverflow, I have a folder `app` on my desktop. The path is something like `MyProjectName\artifacts\bin\MyProjectName\Debug\app`. But there is no `approot`. Did I miss or mess up something? What is the normal path of the container?

Comment: Sorry I'm not an ASP.NET user so I cannot help.

Comment: @warmoverflow, thanks. I found web at `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp`.  `#!/usr/bin/env bash
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do # resolve $SOURCE until the file is no longer a symlink
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE" # if $SOURCE was a relative symlink, we need to resolve it relative to the path where the symlink file was located
done
DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
exec "dnx" --project "$DIR/src/HelloDocker" --configuration Release web "$@"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use the same container and just overwrite the previous image

You can't. For a new image you need to create a new container. Keep in mind that it is early days for docker on windows, the VS docker extension is preview software.

Probably not so easy with azure but generally you would set up a clean up cron that periodically purges old images and stopped containers on the docker host.